# Upgrade of Hyperledger fabric from 1.4.2 to 2.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to upgrade our current network setup in fabric 1.4.2 to 2.0. We have a kubernetes setup. I see in the documentation that first we need to upgrade the peer database by using  `peer node upgrade-dbs` and then start the peer. But since this command doesnot exist with peer version 1.4.2 I cannot do it from the running peer pod. when I tried to change the peer image to 2.0 version I get error following error. `Error in instantiating ledger provider: unexpected format. db info = [leveldb for channel-IDs at [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/ledgerProvider]], data format = [], expected format = [2.0]`

How can I upgrade the peer database and start the peer pod in kubernetes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue my manually deleting the couchDB database and then starting the peer with 2.0 image